# Maximize the value of matrix after doing a specific matrix operation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

[image: Problem description]

I have tried to solve the problem. But , was unsuccessful.

My approach so far :

1. Store all the combinations in a temporary 2D array.
2. Visit one by one cell of the matrix and update the current cell and adjacent
   cell.
3. Then storing the value of matrix given by the equation in an auxiliary array ,
   which takes O(n^2)
4. Now , comparing the results.

This is giving me , TLE. I am not able to come up with overlapping subproblems here.

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to deal with combinations at all. It can be shown that the the following conditions on matrix should met: 
1. The sum of modified matrixes elements should be equal to the sum of elements of the original matrix.
2. Each element should be in range [1,M]

So the algorithm may be described as:

1. Calculate the sum of original matrix elements, S.
2. Fill matrix with ones
3. Calculate the difference D = S - N*N.
4. Moving from bottom right corner, fill elements with value V = min(D, M),
5. decrease D by V, repeat 4 until D>0

Comment: First of all , a very big "thank you" for your help. I seriously mean it. 

Now , coming to point , can you please clear some of the doubts which I am having ?

`Calculate the sum of original matrix elements, S.` --> Do you mean row wise traversal ?
`Fill matrix with ones` -- That is the auxiliary array , right ?

Comment: You can calculate sum of elements traversing all elements of the matrix. You can fill auxiliary array our fill the original matrix - it does not matter since you have the sum of matrix elements